# Algebraic and Holomorphic Functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I was reading [link text](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10724/relationship-between-algebraic-and-holomorphic-differential-forms)
and these two much simpler questions occurred to me: 
(i)  What type of algebraic functions on complex *projective* varieties do the holomorphic functions correspond to? The rational functions?
(ii) What type of algebraic functions on complex *algebraic* varieties do the holomorphic functions correspond to? The affine coordinate ring?

Comment: By "algebraic function" do you mean "regular"?

Comment: I mean one that can be represented as a quotient of polynomials.


Comment: so, yes, I mean regular.



Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, here's a few theorems that might help:

1: On a complex projective variety, a function that is meromorphic on the whole variety is a rational function.  You can get this out of the embedding into projective space.

2: On a compact complex manifold, the only globally holomorphic functions are constant.  This follows from the maximum principle.

Additionally, if you're looking locally, then on an affine variety, there are a LOT more holomorphic functions than algebraic functions.  On $\mathbb{C}$, you have $\mathbb{C}[z]$ for the algebraic functions, and convergent power series for holomorphic, so $e^z$ is holo but not algebraic.  But every algebraic function is holomorphic.

Comment: But the two sphere $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a compact complex manifold? Surely the coordinate functions $x,y,z$ (where $x(a,b,c) = a$) are holomorphic?

Comment: They're real-valued functions on $S^2=\mathbb{CP}^1$, and so can't be holomorphic, they're smooth though.

Comment: Then take $SU(n,\mathbb{C})$: it's a compact complex manifold, the coordinate functions $t^i_j$ are complex valued, and must be holomorphic? No?

Comment: It actually is only a real Lie group; the complexification is $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$, which of course *isn't* compact.

Comment: Maybe not a complex Lie group, but still a complex manifold.

Comment: If you mean by $SU(n, \mathbb{C})$ the usual special unitary group then no, it isn't even a complex manifold.  Take $SU(2)$ for example: this is 3 real-dimensional, so surely not complex.  If you mean by $SU(n,\mathbb{C})$ the complexification of $SU(n)$, then my last comment holds.

Comment: Matt is completely right.  Just because something is defined in complex numbers doesn't make it a complex manifold (hint: is there a conjugation happening somewhere?)

Comment: But it has an almost-complex structure?


Comment: Nope.  The dimension of $SU(n)$ is always $n^2-1$, so take $n$ even, like 2 or 4, and you get an odd dimensional manifold, and almost complex structures can only arise on even dimensional manifolds.  It's VERY much a real manifold, just defined using complex numbers and the conjugation operator.

Comment: Ok, last try: but it is, at least, a complex affine variety.

Comment: It is the same class of object as the real axis in the complex plane, which is to say: essentially not complex at all.

Comment: Matt's got it, there's no complex structure involved at all.  Again, complex things have even dimension (as real things) whereas the things you're talking about have odd dimension as real things, so they can't even hope to be complex, they're just like the axes in the plane.

Answer (score 5):

On a complex (connected, reduced...) projective variety, the only holomorphic functions are constants, by the maximum principle. The interesting comparison theorem is the following :(algebraic) rational functions are the same as (analytic) meromorphic functions. It is a consequence of GAGA, but it is a much simpler statement that was known long before Serre.

If the variety is not supposed projective anymore, the holomorphic functions have no reason at all to be algebraic : the exponential function on $\mathbb{C}$ is not !

Comment: Ahh, you just barely beat me to it!

Comment: Sorry... Our answers are astonishingly close in time and content !

Comment: Clearly, we're both completely, 100% correct, then.  Except for my typo, corrected by Mariano.

Comment: "If the variety is not supposed projective anymore, the holomorphic functions have no reason at all to be algebraic": By Noether normalization, any irreducible complex variety of positive dimension has non-algebraic meromorphic functions.  What can be said about holomorphic functions on affine varieties?  Incomplete varieties?  



Comment: I don't think I understand your question. An irreducible complex variety of positive dimension has no non-algebraic meromorphic functions if it is projective ! (Note that by meromorphic, we mean at most poles as singularities).

Noether's normalization argument shows indeed that there are non-algebraic holomorphic functions on positive-dimensional affine algebraic varieties.



Comment: @Olivier: Sorry, the word "affine" was missing in the second sentence.  The first quesion was not so great: I temporarily forgot about the affine version of Noether normalization.  But what about the second question?  If a variety is complete, its complex analytic space is compact, so carries no nonconstant holomorphic functions.  Conversely?

Comment: It is easy to construct a non-complete variety that has no non-constant holomorphic functions, like projective plane minus a point 
(Hartogs's lemma).

Answer (score 3):

We have the following theorem due to [S.T.Yau and Uhlenbeck](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.3160390714/abstract) which play an important rule in regularity theory of solutions of Hermitian-Einstein metric on stable vector bundles

> Any weakly holomorphic map into a projectively algebraic manifold is
>   rational.

Definition:For a weakly holomorphic map from the ball $B \subset \mathbb C^n$ into an algebraic manifold $M$, We
assume that $M$ is isometrically embedded in $\mathbb CP^k$ which is embedded in some
Euclidian space $\mathbb R^N$. The map $F : B\to M \subset \mathbb  R^N$ is then a vector-valued map and it makes sense to say that it is $L_1^2$.  When $n > 1$, we call $F$ weakly holomorphic if for any linear holomorphic
coordinate system $\{ z_l,...,z_n\}$ on $B$ and for almost every point $\{ z_2;..., z_n\}$ the
restrictions of $F$ to each complex line in the $z_1$ variable is weakly holomorphic.