# Loop space: De Rham cohomology

Tags: frechet-manifold, reference-request

How to calculate  the DeRham cohomology of the free loop space $LM= C^\infty(S^1,M)$ as a Frechet manifold?.

Edit: It  will be enough for me to know: 
When $H^1_{DR}(LM)$ is not $\{0\}$.

Bounty is ending within 5 hours.

Comment: This might be of interest http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48637/homology-of-the-loop-space . Once you computed the homology of the based loop space, it is possible via the free loop space fibration $\Omega M\rightarrow \Lambda M\rightarrow M$ to write down spectral sequence which relates the homologies of $M,\Omega M$, and $\Lambda M$.

Comment: I would talk to Andrew Stacey or Patrick Iglesias-Zemmour.

Comment: Of course the question I linked is asking fof singular homology. I do not know anything about the De-Rham complex on infinite dimensional spaces.


Comment: I would probably start with Chen's papers on iterated integrals, such as http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=380859

Comment: What kind of differential forms are you thinking of when you say "de Rham cohomology" in the context Frechet manifold? In case you need this for $LM:=C^0(S^1,M)$ and for singular cohomology then a lot more can be said; the Betti numbers of $LM$ can be computed for a large class of $M$. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equivariant de Rham theory in precisely this setting seems to be developed by Leandre in "Equivariant Cohomology, Fock Space and Loop Groups" (2006). (http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/staff/fa_rogers/ECFSLG.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that de Rham cohomology is ordinary cohomology (which shouldn't be too hard by the standard sheaf-theoretic proof?), $H^1 = Hom(\pi_1,\mathbb{R})$. Now the base point fibration gives rise to a short exact sequence
$$
1 \rightarrow \pi_2(M) \rightarrow \pi_1(LM) \rightarrow \pi_1(M) \rightarrow 1
$$
Hence yes, if $H^1(M;\mathbb{R}) \neq 0$, then also $H^1(LM;\mathbb{R}) \neq 0$. Maybe more importantly, in the simply-connected case $H^1(LM) = H^2(M)$, something that one can also see by hand.

Comment: It's better to say why the base point fibration (you perhaps mean the loop space fibration $\Omega M\to LM\to M$) gives a short exact sequence. In general, you get a long exact sequence; here it splits to short exact sequence as the fibration has a section. Another point to note is that $LM$ is not connected if $M$ has a fundamental group.

Comment: +1 for "see by hand" :)

Comment: @eigenbunny: Note: your short exact sequence comes equipped with a section $\pi_1(M) \to \pi_1(LM)$ induced by the inclusion of constant loops. Hence $\pi_1(LM)$ is a semi-direct product of $\pi_1(M)$ by
$\pi_2(M)$.

Comment: @John, eigenbunny - If $M$ is not simply connected then $LM$ is not connected; therefore, $\pi_1(LM)$ is meaningless unless you specify which component. The constant section only provides a section for $L_0M \to M$, where $L_0 M$ is the component of constant loops. The components of $LM$ are indexed by the conjugacy classes in $\pi_1(M)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is comment rather than answer:  Please check it, whether it makes sense...

Corollary 2.6 page 11 of [Free Loop space and homology by J.L Loday](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~loday/PAPERS/FreeLoop4.pdf) says that 
For any simply  connected space, there is a functorial isomorphism:
$$HH_1 (\Omega^1(M)) \cong H^1(LM)$$
And  [Hochschild-Kostant-Rosenberg theorem](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hochschild-Kostant-Rosenberg+theorem)  says that: For a k-algebra $R$, its module of Kähler differentials coincides with its first Hochschild homology
$$\Omega_1(R/k)\cong HH_1(R)$$

Now we have by this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6074/kahler-differentials-and-ordinary-differentials/6138#6138), a surjective map $\Omega_1(C^\infty(M))\to \Omega^1(M)$.

So can we say that $H^1(LM)= \Omega_1(C^\infty(M))$ and if $\Omega^1(M)\neq \{0\}$, we have $H^1(LM)\neq \{0\}$ for simply connected finite dimension manifold $M$.

Comment: this fails to take into account the internal grading or... in what sense is $\Omega^1$ a ring?  see eigenbunny for the correct result.