# Module of Kahler differentials for manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, universal-property, kahler-differentials

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra and let $\mathcal{M}_A$ be the set of all $A$-modules. In $\mathcal{M}_A$, there exists a universal object $\Omega_{A/k}$,  called the module of Kahler differentials, and a $k$-derivation $d: A \to \Omega_{A/k}$ such that for any $k$-derivation $D: A \to M$ there exists a map $f: \Omega_{A/k} \to M$ such that $f\circ d = D$.

I'm trying to understand what this object has to be when I look at manifolds that are also smooth affine varities. I think that the answer should be the space of sections of the cotangent bundle over the ring of $C^\infty$ functions on the manifold. I'm unable to figure out how to show this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The module of Kähler differentials algebraically is known to be different from the module of smooth Kähler differentials (for $C^\infty$-rings). This is folklore to me, but I have seen it several times, including on the nLab page on Kähler differentials.

Comment: This page should have the details you want: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smooth+algebra . It uses Quillen's characterization of the module category and the Kähler differentials as a section of the module bifibration.  A question I have is how does smooth Quillen cohomology relate to De Rham cohomology.

Comment: This has been answered in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6074/kahler-differentials-and-ordinary-differentials/6138#6138).