# Algebras which admit tensor calculus and (pseudo-)Riemannian geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

It's an often observed fact that the basic notions of analysis on manifolds and (pseudo-)Riemannian geometry, such as tensors, connections and curvature, can be defined in purely algebraic terms. The protagonist of this is the algebra of smooth functions $C^\infty(M)$ on a manifold $M$: the observation that tensors on $M$ can be defined as $C^\infty(M)$-multilinear maps enables the algebraic definitions of connection, Riemann curvature tensor, etc. This observation in turn derives from the fact that the module of derivations on this algebra is [dualizable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable+object), or equivalently finitely generated projective.

Therefore, if $k$ is a field and $A$ a commutative $k$-algebra, then we can develop the basic notions of (pseudo-)Riemannian geometry over $A$ as soon as the module of derivations $\mathrm{Der}_k(A)$ is f.g. projective [1].

> Besides $C^\infty(M)$, what are examples of algebras for which the module of derivations $\mathrm{Der}_k(A)$ is f.g. projective?

Some formulas in differential geometry also require division by $2$ or $3$, so let me restrict to the case $\mathrm{char}(k) \neq 2,3$.

Here's what I know so far:

- For $\mathrm{char}(k) = 0$ and $A$ a finitely generated domain, this is essentially what the [Zariski-Lipman conjecture is about](https://mathoverflow.net/a/366244).
- One could hope to find natural candidates for further examples by looking at suitable subalgebras of $C^\infty(M)$, e.g. by imposing certain decay conditions on the functions. However, I have not yet found any decay condition that works.
- The $\mathbb{C}$-algebra of holomorphic functions on a domain $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ is an example, since its module of derivations is [free of finite rank](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1385725889800010).

Because of the first item, and because $C^\infty(M)$ is not finitely generated, I'm only interested in **non-finitely generated examples**, of which I hope to see more in the answers.

---

[1] I'm not sure who to attribute this too. It appears in slightly different form in [Riemannian manifolds as Lie-Rinehart algebras](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/retrieve/417015) by Pessers and van der Veken (2016), and in a stronger version in Geroch's [Einstein algebras](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-26/issue-4/Einstein-algebras/cmp/1103858122.pdf) (1972) and a few follow-up papers in the philosophy of general relativity. Is there more work that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; as per request of the OP, this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136526/discussion-on-question-by-tobias-fritz-algebras-which-admit-tensor-calculus-and).