Tangent bundles through Serre-Swan
As an exercise, I've been trying to treat some foundational results in differential geometry as algebraically as possible. One of the most fundamental concepts is the tangent bundle of a smooth manifold; I am seeking a purely algebraic definition of this.
By Serre-Swan, vector bundles over a smooth manifold $M$ are the same as finite projective modules over the ring $C^{\infty}(M)$ of smooth functions.
One can define the module of global sections of the tangent bundle of $M,$ as the module $D$ whose elements are $\mathbb{R}$-linear functions $d : C^{\infty}(M)\to C^{\infty}(M)$ obeying the Leibniz rule.
However, can one prove that this module $D$ is finite projective without already having access to the tangent bundle?
I'd be equally happy to accept an answer about the cotangent bundle, if that is easier.

Work locally so that you may assume $M = \mathbb R^n$, then use Lemma 2.1 of Milnor's Morse Theory

If I interpret your question correctly, then the following MO thread seems relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366224/sufficient-conditions-for-mathrmder-ka-to-be-f-g-projective

@JoshuaMundinger Can one check that a module over a non-Noetherian ring is finitely generated by working locally?

@MichaelBarz Working locally is sufficient for checking projectivity. For finite generation, I think you need to use more about manifolds. The Whitney embedding theorem suffices to prove finite generation, and Whitney embedding is also used in the proof of Serre-Swan. I encourage you to try to find a space $X$ with a smooth structure which is not second countable such that $D$ is not finitely generated.

@JoshuaMundinger I am not sure that you can check projectivity locally without assuming any finite generation; furthermore, I believe one can prove Serre-Swan without Whitney embedding; the idea to show finite generation is to prove that the global sections are a dualizable module, which is because all vector bundles are dualizable and the global sections functor is symmetric monoidal. With Whitney embedding one can prove finite generation of this $D,$ but I am curious if it is essential.

@MichaelBarz the global sections functor is not symmetric monoidal for general sheaves, and I don't see if this is true/how you can prove this for sheaves of $C^\infty$-modules without using topological facts again (e.g. partitions of unity)? Descent of projectivity: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/058B.

@JoshuaMundinger Ah, thanks! I think I need to rethink some things.

A proof can be found in Nestruev Smooth Manifolds and observables.
