# Jet Nestruev's proof that the exterior derivative $d$ on a real line is not a Kähler differential $d_{C^\infty(\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, smooth-manifolds, kahler-differentials, differential-algebra

The relation between the exterior derivative $d:C^\infty(\mathbb{R})\to\Omega^1\mathbb(\mathbb{R})$ and the Kähler differential $d_{C^\infty(\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{R}}:C^\infty(\mathbb{R})\to\Omega_{C^\infty(\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{R}}$ has been already explained in [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6074/kahler-differentials-and-ordinary-differentials/9723). More precisely, the exterior derivative do not satisfy universal property expected from Kähler differentials.

While reading the new edition of Jet Nestruev’s [Smooth Manifolds and Observables](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-45650-4), I came across section 14.10 which proves the above statement but using simpler tools compared to the MO thread mentioned previously. However, I do not understand a few steps. I will explain the reasoning and point out the steps which I struggle with.

Let $A$ denote the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra of smooth functions on the real line, i.e., $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. We want to show that $d_{A/\mathbb{R}}e^x\neq e^xd_{A/\mathbb{R}}x$. The proof goes as follows:

1. We show that $x$ and $e^x$ from $A$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{R}$. Thus $\mathbb{R}[x, e^x]\cong \mathbb{R}[X, Y]$ as $\mathbb{R}$-algebras.
2. Since $S:=\mathbb{R}[x, e^x]\setminus \{0\}$ is a multiplicative set of $A$, we can localize $A$ by $S$. Let’s set $A_1:=S^{-1}A$.
3. Additionally, $\mathbb{R}[x, e^x]$ is a domain (as a ring), so that $F:=S^{-1}\mathbb{R}[x, e^x]$ is a field.
4. Let $\delta:=\frac{\partial}{\partial Y}$ (or $\frac{\partial}{\partial e^x}$ if one prefers) be a derivation on the ring $\mathbb{R}[x, e^x]$ induced from $\mathbb{R}[X, Y]$. Using the formula for differentiating fractions, we extend $\delta$ to $F$.
5. Let $I$ be some maximal ideal of $A_1$. Then the field $\bar F:=A_1/I$ contains an isomorphic image of the field $F$, i.e., we have an inclusion $\iota:F\hookrightarrow \bar F$
6. Since $\bar F$ is a field of characteristic zero, the derivation $\delta$ can be extended from $F$ to $\bar F$; let $\bar\delta$ denote that extension.
7. Then $\bar\delta(\bar x)=\overline{\delta(x)}=0$ and $\bar\delta(\overline{e^x})=\overline{\delta(e^x)}=1$, where $\bar{z}=z$ mod $I$ for $z\in A_1$, i.e., $\bar{z}\in A_1/I=\bar{F}$ (see point 5.).
8. Denote the composition $A\to A_1\to\bar{F}\xrightarrow{\bar\delta}\bar{F}$ by $\partial$. It is a $\mathbb{R}$-derivation with values in the $A$-module $\bar{F}$, such that $\partial(x)=0$ and $\partial(e^x)=1$.
9. Due to the universal property of $d_{A/\mathbb{R}}$, there is a $A$-linear homomorphism $h:\Omega_{A/\mathbb{R}}\to\bar{F}$, such that $\partial=h\circ d_{A/\mathbb{R}}$.
10. Since $e^x\partial(x)\neq\partial(e^x)$ (see point 8.), so too $e^xd_{A/\mathbb{R}}x\neq d_{A/\mathbb{R}}e^x$ (see point 9.).

The points 1-4 are easy to follow. In 5, I do not understand why the field $\bar{F}$ must contain an isomorphic image of $F$. In 6, I do not understand why we can extend the derivation from $F$ to $\bar{F}$. Points 7-10 are also clear to me.

In summary, can you give me an explanation of points 5 and 6?

Comment: 5. From the injection $\mathbb{R}[x,e^x]\hookrightarrow A$ we get a homomorphism $F\rightarrow A_1\rightarrow \bar{F}$. A homomorphism of fields is always injective.   $\ \ $
 
 
 
6. In characteristic $0$, a derivation of $F$ always extends  to a derivation of $\bar{F}$ — see for instance Lang's Algebra, ch. VIII, §5.

Comment: Note that the statement which is actually proved is the following: let $A$ be a $K$-algebra ($K$ a field, $\operatorname{char}(K)=0 $), and let $x,y\in A$ be algebraically independent. Then $dx,dy$ are linearly independent (over $A$) in $\Omega _{A/K}$.

Comment: @abx Your explanation of 5 makes it clear. I guess I will try to digest 6 next year :P. Wow, you abstracted the essence of the proof in a elegant and compact manner. The one thing which still bothers me is the hidden use of AC in taking maximal ideal $I$ in 5. I wonder if $I$ can be selected in some more concreate manner, but maybe it deserves a separate thread.